# looping over columns and rows in python which requires using previous elements

Tags: python, pandas, loops

suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

data={'col1':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c'], 'col2':['small','big','small','big','big','small', 'big','big','small']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','col2'])

print(df)

I would like to generate and indicator variable that if in col2 the variable changes from small to big then assign 1 else 0. This should be done per factor in col1. The solution should look like something like this:

the null could also be replaced with 0.
data={'col1':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c'], 'col2':['small','big','small','big','big','small', 'big','big','small'], 'ind':[null,1,0,null,0,null,1,0,0,]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','col2','ind'])

print(df)

This is only a small sample.

Comment: can you please format the question properly. use triple backticks ` to create code

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple to do as a vectorised solution with `numpy` `where()`

```
import numpy as np
data={'col1':['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c'], 'col2':['small','big','small','big','big','small', 'big','big','small']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','col2'])
df = df.assign(ind=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.col2.eq("big") # current row
                                   &dfa.col2.shift().eq("small") # previous row
                                   &df.col1.eq(df.col1.shift()) # same "factor"
                                   ,1,0))
```

### output

```
col1  col2  ind
   a small    0
   a   big    1
   a small    0
   b   big    0
   b   big    0
   c small    0
   c   big    1
   c   big    0
   c small    0
```